# Xcode environment not dark in Mojave beta's dark mode

Tags: xcode, beta-seed-program, mojave

I feel really stupid for asking this, but here goes:

Is there a button or setting somewhere to make Xcode use dark mode for its environment in the Mojave Beta?

Searching for this renders a lot of questions about dark mode in High Sierra, or how to make your programs adjust to dark mode, but what I want is for Xcode *itself* to use dark mode, which just doesn't happen on my 2015 MBP with Mojave Beta. I guess Xcode, being an Apple product and all, should detect that OS X is in Dark Mode and adjust accordingly?

Comment: Try running this in Terminal: `defaults write http://com.apple.dt.Xcode NSWindowDarkChocolate -bool true `

Comment: What versions of Mojave and Xcode beta are you using?

Comment: Mojave 10.14 Beta (18A353d) and Xcode Version 9.4.1 (9F2000).

Comment: You need to use Xcode 10 beta, in order to use dark mode.  Xcode 9 does not support dark mode.

Comment: That was it! Xcode 10 beta works like charm. Thanks for helping me out!

Answer (score 3):

For Dark Mode to work, I needed Xcode 10 beta. Thanks to user128998 for helping me out!